# Mount EFS to Save Space?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, mount, amazon-efs

On my EC2, I have mounted an AWS EFS pointing to the Jenkins home directory, `/var/lib/jenkins`. I did this "with the hope" to stop occupying more space in my `/`.

What I did was following:

1. I copied `/var/lib/jenkins` to /tmp
2. I mounted EFS points to `/var/lib/jenkins`.
3. I copied back all the files from `/tmp to` /var/lib/jenkins`.
4. I `chown`ed new files that I copied back to jenkins:jenkins.

jenkins runs successfully, and by running `df -h`, I can see that I am writing new files on EFS (%1). But I also see that I am still occupying more space on `/` -which is what I wanted to avoid!

I know I am missing something obvious here! but is there any way that I can use EFS without adding more files in `/` (root folder)?

This is part of `df -h` results, to clarify:

`/dev/xvda1          156G   97G   59G  63% /'  EFS_IP:/     8.0E   31G  8.0E   1% /var/lib/jenkins`

Is anything stored in `/var/lib/jenkins/ (EFS Mount Point) is part of '/dev/xvda1` or not?

Comment: Don't you need to *move* (not copy) the files?  Mounting something over the top of a directory just makes the files there inaccessible... it doesn't free up any space.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot

I have updated my post.